# I cannot insert and display more than 13 References in Springer Nature compiled in Overleaf

Tags: springernature

I am using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd but although I removed the examples in **sn-bibliography.bib** file and tried to exceed the number of the References, which initially where 13, I don't see them depicted in the compiled file...

I start the 14th Reference according to the examples, for instance:

```
%% Journal article with DOI
@article{bib14, ......
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? Is there any other place in the rest of the example files where I configure the maximum size of the References? I searched in all files, I didn't find something...

Comment: you can have literally thousands of entries in a bib file (it is a very bad style to name them `bib1`, `bib2`, ...) so whatever error you have it is not the number of entries, it may be the 14th entry that you added has a syntax error. But if you do not show the code or the error message we can not help

Comment: do you have a `\cite{bib14}` in your document? Just adding it to the bib file will not  make it appear in the output. A `bib` file is a database of _potential_ references that you can cite using `\cite`

Comment: @David Carlisle: I do not know, I will check now the files...

Comment: @David Carlisle: You are awesome!!! Many thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `\cite{bib14}` in your document? Just adding it to the bib file will not make it appear in the output. A bib file is a database of potential references that you can cite using `\cite`

Note  it is better to use symbolic key names based on the article title or author so you see things like `\cite{smith2022}` rather than `\cite{bib14}` which works but makes the source hard to read and is confusing if that citation ends up as **[2]** or some other number that isn't 14.